# Get post ID from the Create post/page admin interface?

Tags: plugin-development

I am adding a meta box in the create post/page interface and I want to get the ID of the post being edited/created so I can dynamically display the value of the input field.

From the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) :

```
/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">' . __("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' ) . '</label> ';
  echo '<input type="text" id= "myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="whatever" size="25" />';
}
```

How do I pass the ID to `myplugin_inner_custom_box()`? So I can use the following within it:

```
// Get the value of the meta key that is associated to the page
  $as_meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'as_link_to_image', true );
```

and replace the `whatever` value with the value of the meta key in the input field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `get_the_ID()` or `global $post; $post->ID`.

Comment: @Joann it isn't documented very well, but admin screens use many of same global variable that front-end does.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my follow up, but `$post` is passed to the metabox callback function as a parameter so no need to get it from `global` space.

Answer (score 5):

Hi **@Joann:**

When creating post admin metaboxes, **the standard way to get the Post's ID in a metabox is via a `$post` parameter in the callback function**. The following is a subset of the code taken [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Callback_args) found the same page you posted but after I updated it to remove 2 bugs:

Hopefully this is self-explanitory?

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box');
function add_my_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box('metabox_id', 'Metabox Title', 'my_metabox_callback', 
      'page', 'normal', 'low');
}
function my_metabox_callback($post, $metabox) {
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_custom_field',true); 
}
```

Comment: It's not easy to spot shoved under the `$callback_args` description(on the codex page linked to by Mike), but every metabox callback will receive the `$post` object as the first parameter, all you need do is include it in your callback function like in Mike's example, eg. `function my_metabox_callback( $post )`

Comment: @Joann - Yes to what @t310s said; I realize now that my words my have sounded like a passive aggressive way to say *"You should have seen it"* but that was absolutely not my intent; it was more to say that there is a reference there in case you need it in the future. And if you *had* found it you would have had to deal with the fact that code had bugs you might not have know how to diagnose; I found and fixed those bugs because of answering this question for you.

Comment: and t31os: Thanks! I tried imitating how the other functions from the sample code retrieve the post ID but it didn't work. Anyways, that's a cleaner way to do it indeed...

Comment: @Joann - Glad we could help.